# exponential transformation of dependent variable in Zelig

Tags: r, r-zelig

I apologize in advance if this question is too esoteric. I am using the Zelig package in R with a log-log regression model:

```
z.out <- zelig(lnDONATIONS ~ lnPRICE + lnFUNDRAISING + lnAGE, model = "ls", data = mydata)
x.out <- setx(z.out)
s.out <- sim(z.out, x = x.out)
summary(s.out)
plot(s.out)
```

This works fine, but I am trying to implement something that is allowed in the Stata-based 'precursor' to Zelig (*clarify*); specifically, in the *clarify* package, after the 'setx' command, you can type in **simqi, tfunc(exp)** in order to get the expected values based on the exponential transformation of the dependent variable (the *simqi* command in Stata is analogous to the *sim* comamnd in R/Zelig). My question is, can this post-*setx* exponential transformation be done in R with the Zelig package, and if so, how? The very extensive Zelig documentation does not seem to have an analogue to the 'tfunc' command in the *clarify* package.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but the Zelig mailing list may be a better place to ask. They have really good support and the developers mostly answer the questions themselves (and quickly too!). See: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.zelig